# Matching up HomeGroup users created in different versions of Windows

Tags: user-accounts, windows-8.1, homegroup

In our household, we have 2 laptops and a desktop, all currently on Windows 8.1.

The desktop has been upgraded in stages from Windows 7. Laptop 1 was bought with Windows 8 and has now been upgraded. Laptop 2 is new and came with Windows 8.1.

We've been trying to set up a HomeGroup such that we have one user on laptop 1, one on laptop 2 and both can log into the desktop, with each user able to edit their files on their laptop and desktop, while the other user has read-only access.

And we now have that situation ... except ... because the user on laptop 1 was created in Windows 8 but the same user on the desktop was created in 8.1, they have different names in Windows Explorer (say, firstuser and first_000). Likewise, the other use was created on laptop 2 in Windows 8.1 and on the desktop in Windows 7 (so let's say secon_000 and seconduser).

This is ultimately confusing. Now if we expand the HomeGroup, we get four users (firstuser, first_000, seconduser and secon_000) and each has a single computer inside it.

What I'd like to see is firstuser => laptop1, desktop and seconduser => laptop2, desktop.

An acceptable alternative is first_000 => laptop1, desktop and secon_000 => laptop2, desktop.

But what I don't want to have to do is delete firstuser and seconduser and rebuild them. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out in the end.

You have to go to your [Microsoft account settings](https://account.live.com/summarypage.aspx) online.

Log in and click on Edit Account Name. Change the name, save it.

Then restart both computers. In future, it will log in using that alias, no matter what your underlying username is. This is the name that shows up in Homegroups in future.